# Using iterators on maps

Tags: c++, stl

```
map<double, LatLon> closestPOI; 
map<double, LatLon> ::iterator iterPOI = closestPOI.begin();
```

I made a tree that is keyed by distance between two points. I need to find the 3 points in this tree that are the smallest (3 smallest distances). I declared an iterator and initialized it to point at the root (I'm not sure if that was necessary but it didn't solve my problem). I tried using advance(iterPOI, 1) to increment the iterator but that didn't work either. How can I find these 3 points and access their values?

Note: Yes I know that the 3 nodes I want are the root and its kids (since they have the smallest distances)

Comment: I'm not sure you're starting with the right data structure.  If I understand correctly, the keys in this case are the distance of the LatLon from some reference point.  What if two LatLons in your data set are the same distance from the reference point?  A std::map will only let you have one LatLon for a given distance.

Comment: Your right but that's highly unlikely (I'm taking a risk)

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy can you think of another way to find the smallest 3 distances to a point without looping, give me a clue if you have something on your mind ;) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you use a `for()` loop to iterate the map:

```
for(map<double, LatLon> ::iterator iterPOI = closestPOI.begin();
    iterPOI != closestPOI.end();
    ++iterPOI) {
    // access the iterator's key: iterPOI->first ...
    // access the iterator's value: iterPOI->second ...
}
```

Comment: what if i only want the first 3 values? Also can I even increment an iterator, if yes where does it point to?

Comment: @ConfusedCoder You count up to three using a separate counter?

Comment: @ConfusedCoder When you have everything you want, you can `return` from the function or `break` from the loop. When you increment an iterator of this type, its moves to the next entry in the map.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a map you can do something like this:  (assuming you're using anything over gcc 4.8.2)

```
map<double, LatLon> closestPOI;
// if you don't have gcc 4.8.2 then do what you did with the iterator in your question...

for(auto i_poi = closestPOI.begin(); i_poi != closestPOI.end(); ++i)
{
    // to get at the double you do: i_poi->first
    // to get at the LatLon you do: i_poi->second 
}
```

Hope that helps a bit

Comment: can I avoid looping I already have another loop I don't want n^2

Comment: I'm not sure if you seen this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Has some useful info on what you can do to a map. I'm pretty sure map has a find

Comment: but the problem is I'm looking for the smallest key, I do not know what these keys are

Comment: A map is ordered by it's key, so the smallest key will be the first entry, and it will be unique as well. If it was a multimap then you'd have multiple keys, but not here.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map This is another reference on map, have a read of it's description. It should help

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of getting the first (i.e, smallest key) three elements of a map. I've aliased `LatLong` to `int` just as an example, so [you can see it in action here](http://rextester.com/XEQQZL84525):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using LatLon = int;

int main()
{
    std::map<double, LatLon> map { { 1.0d, 1 }, { 2.0d, 2 }, { 3.0d, 3 }, { 0.5d, 4 } };

    // Get the three closest points and store them in a vector
    std::vector<LatLon> closest;
    for ( const auto& pair : map ) {
        if ( closest.size() >= 3 )
            break;
        closest.push_back(pair.second);
    }

    // Do something with the three closest points
    for ( auto latlon : closest )
        std::cout << latlon << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Note that if there are less than 3 points in your map to begin with, your `closest` vector will also have less than 3 elements.